# PHP: The use of objects and how to properly use them

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm been working on a PHP problem that deals with objects but so far I'm having a bit trouble.

The requirements:

1. Define a class Vehicle which has protected properties: make, model, year, price. Create a constructor method that takes in make, model, year, and price. Implement a public method displayObject() to display the properties of each object instance.
2. Define a derived class LandVehicle that inherits from the Vehicle class and contains a private property:  maxSpeed. You may need to override the constructor and displayObject() method for this derived class.
3. Define another derived class WaterVehicle that also inherits from the Vehicle class and contains private property: boatCapacity. You may need to override the constructor and displayObject() method for this derived class.
4. Instantiate (Create) at least three objects of LandVehicle and display the properties of each object instance.
5. Instantiate (Create) at least three objects of WaterVehicle and display the properties of each object instance.

My code at the moment:

```
class Vehicle {

protected int $make;
protected int $model;
protected int $year;
protected int $price;

function_construct() {
    $this->make = "";
    $this->model = "";
    $this->year = "";
    $this->price = "";
}

function_construct($make, $model, $year, $price) {
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->year = $year;
    $this->price = $price;
}

public function displayObject() {
    return $this->$make . " " . $this->$model . " " . $this->$year . " " . $this->$price; 
}
}

class LandVehicle extends Vehicle {

private int maxSpeed;
protected int $make;
protected int $model;
protected int $year;
protected int $price;
}   

class WaterVehicle extends Vehicle {

private int boatCapacity;
protected int $make;
protected int $model;
protected int $year;
protected int $price;
}
```

At the moment, the class (Vehicle) has been declared with the 4 variables: make, model, year, and price. I have the displayObject() method down (unless If I did something wrong). I was able to make the new derived classes: LandVehicle and WaterVehicle by inheriting the Vehicle class. Those were the easy parts. The hard part is how do you override the constructor and displayObject() method for the derived classes? Is it simply an echo statement or is there more to it. Should I create a for, while, or even foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the parent methods using the `parent` keyword:

```
class Vehicle
{
  protected $make;
  protected $model;
  protected $year;
  protected $price;

  public function __construct($make, $model, $year, $price)
  {
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->year = $year;
    $this->price = $price;
  }

  public function displayObject()
  {
    return $this->make . " " . $this->model . " " . $this->year . " " . $this->price; 
  }
}

class LandVehicle extends Vehicle
{
  protected $maxSpeed;

  public function __construct($make, $model, $year, $price, $maxSpeed)
  {
    parent::__construct($make, $model, $year, $price);

    $this->maxSpeed = $maxSpeed;
  }

  public function displayObject()
  {
    return parent::displayObject() . ' ' . $this->maxSpeed; 
  }
}
```

Do the same for the water vehicles.